# Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt in Intellij Idea

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Today when I refresh the spring boot project in Intellij Idea `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)`, show error like this:

```
Unable to find method ''org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetContainer org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPluginExtension.getSourceSets()''
'org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetContainer org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPluginExtension.getSourceSets()'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I have already tried:

- restart IDE
- invalidate cache and restart IDE
- stop gradle build process and restart IDE
- remove the ./gradle/wrapper/dist folder
- change the gradle version in gradle/wrapper folder

both did not fixed this problem, why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem? BTW, when I using this command `./gradlew clean :dolphin-post:dolphin-post-service:build -x test` to build project in terminal:

```
➜  dolphin-post git:(master) ✗ ./gradlew clean :dolphin-post:dolphin-post-service:build -x test
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.1-all.zip
...............10%...............20%...............30%...............40%...............50%................60%...............70%...............80%...............90%...............100%

Welcome to Gradle 7.4.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Aggregated test and JaCoCo reports
 - Marking additional test source directories as tests in IntelliJ
 - Support for Adoptium JDKs in Java toolchains

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :dolphin-acientbay
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/retire
> Configure project :dolphin-post
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/retire/build.gradle'
> Configure project :dolphin-template
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/retiretemplate/build.gradle'
> Task :dolphin-common:compileJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :dolphin-post:dolphin-post-service:compileJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 58s
17 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

works fine.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same JDK and Gradle in IDE as in the terminal. `why did this happen?` as shown in error message description it is oftec caused by the incompatible versions of Gradle plugins/JDK/Gradle used in build. Try to remember if you have changed anything for this build. Try using different version if Gradle and JDK in IDE Gradle settings they are specified in Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle.